# correct template location for django generics?

Tags: python, django, templates

According to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders), the template loader will

> load templates from Django apps on the filesystem. For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory.

going on:

> ...then get_template('foo.html') will look for foo.html in these directories, in this order:

```
/path/to/myproject/polls/templates/
/path/to/myproject/music/templates/
```

---

So... inside my "**website**" project, I have a "**www**" app. So the directory structure is **/path/to/project/website/www/**

I created a "**templates**" directory inside "**www**", and put there "**page_list.html**" (**/path/to/project/website/www/page_list.html**)

The app is listed inside "INSTALLED_APPS", but when I try to do this in urls.py:

```
url('^$', ListView.as_view(model=Page,))
```

I get "*TemplateDoesNotExist*", and the error says that **django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader** is  looking for "**/path/to/project/website/templates/www/page_list.html**" or **/path/to/project/website/www/templates/www/page_list.html**

If I put the template inside **website/www/templates/www**, it works... but I wonder why it works this way. It seems absurd to have a **templates** folder inside the app folder, and then to have yet another one named as the application inside the **templates** directory....

And the documentation says it should be looking inside of **project/app/templates**... 
I do have

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Although the docs for app_directories.Loader don't say that you need it (and also tried removing that option).

What's going on? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it something about the generic views, or is there something else afoot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the automatic template naming of Django's generic class based views. If you use `django.views.generic.ListView` you got the [MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin) which creates your template name `www/poll_list.html`. This name is combined with the prefix generated by the [app_directory Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) so you got `/path/to/project/app/templates/www/poll_list.html`.

You if you don't want this you have different option (in this order):

- Use the template_name argument or attribute in your view.
- Subclass the MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin and strip out the app prefix. Then mix it in your views.
- Don't use the app_directory loader.