# Cookiecutter Django - ListView expects templates in different directory to Views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, cookiecutter-django

Cookiecutter generates the app `users` automatically under `my_project` directory. I've placed `my_app` in the same directory / listed it under `INSTALLED_APPS` and it works fine. I then created my templates folder under `my_project/templates/my_app/` (same as the generated `users` templates).

When using a View, I received a `TemplateDoesNotExistError`. So Instead, I put templates under `my_project/my_app/templates` in which case it worked. When I used ListView, I recieved the same error. So I moved this template to the previous folder, and it works.

```
- requirements
- my_project
    - contrib
    ▒   - sites
    ▒       - migrations
    - static
    ▒   - css
    ▒   - fonts
    ▒   - images
    ▒   ▒   - favicons
    ▒   - js
    - templates
    ▒   - account
    ▒   - pages
    ▒   - my_app
    ▒           - item_list.html <- only works here (ListView)
    ▒   - users
    - my_app
    ▒   - migrations
    ▒   - templates
    ▒           - item_detail.html <- only works here (View)
    - users
    ▒   - migrations
    ▒   - tests
    - utils
```

What am I missing here? I would like to keep my templates together in one folder obviously. If I switch the templates/directories around, I get `TemplateDoesNotExistError`.

These are my relevant (I think?) settings.

`settings/base.py`

```
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "my_project"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "my_project.users",
    "my_project.my_app",
    ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [str(APPS_DIR / "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "my_project.users.context_processors.allauth_settings",
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

`my_project/my_app/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "my_project.my_app"
    verbose_name = _("My_App") # not really this but you get it

    def ready(self):
        try:
            import my_project.my_app.signals  # noqa F401
        except ImportError:
            pass
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044982/4916945), maybe I've misconfigured the `INSTALLED_APP`?

> 4. add `<project_slug>.<name-of-the-app>.apps.<NameOfTheAppConfigClass>`, on
>    your LOCAL_APPS on config/settings/base.py

EDIT: `my_project.my_app.apps.MyAppConfig` added to LOCAL_APPS and doesn't make a difference...

Comment: The answer to this question [correct template location for django generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767954/correct-template-location-for-django-generics) gives a good explanation of what is happening with templates for generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 hours later I re-did the entire cookiecutter django process [following a well written guide](https://dev.to/highcenburg/creating-a-blog-with-cookiecutter-django-deploying-it-to-heroku-introduction-2842), then copied over my models, views, urls, templates - and the issue was still there...

Thankfully the guide shows many view examples (unlike the docs!) and I noticed my view:

```
class ItemView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    """ Item Detail """

    template_name = "item.html"
```

should have been:

```
class ItemView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    """ Item Detail """

    template_name = "my_app/item.html"
```

Now everything lives happily under the same template folder.